# What is the difference between these two array assignments in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6

I am working on Angular 4 application.

I found below code in my application but unable to find exact purpose of below code.

```
getManagementView(groupField: string) {        
    this.auditList = [...this.auditList.filter(this.filterByRevisit)];
  }
```

I changed it to below code both are working fine.

```
getManagementView(groupField: string) {        
    this.auditList = this.auditList.filter(this.filterByRevisit);
  }
```

Could any one help me to understand what is the difference in above two code blocks.

Comment: Seems to me some people fall in love with the `...` operator and misapply it a lot.

Comment: The question in your title is not the same as in the description.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is noting different. The [**spread (...)**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) operator destroys the array and gives back the elements one by one and then in the `[]` put them into the  making again an array. Which is actually extra operation.

So `this.auditList.filter(this.filterByRevisit)` returns an array, 
and this `[...this.auditList.filter(this.filterByRevisit)]` returns an array which is spread and again makes an array.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there is a difference between the two. `...` would create a new array, `filter` already did it.

However if I take the title:

```
this.array = this.array      // does nothing, same object
this.array = [...this.array] // creates a new array, though the same content
```